# Redirect lines between patterns to separate files

Tags: shell-script, awk

Need to separate out lines between two repetitive patterns from an input file and redirect every selection of lines to separate files.

Example Input File Format:
    `Pattern 1`
    `Line1`
    `Line2`
    `Line3`
    `Pattern 2`
    `Pattern 1`
    `Line4`
    `Line5`
    `Pattern 2`

Outoput Files:
File 1:
    `Pattern 1`
    `Line1`
    `Line2`
    `Line3`
    `Pattern 2`

File 2:
    `Pattern 1`
    `Line4`
    `Line5`
    `Pattern 2`

How can this be done as part of shell scripting? I have this following awk command implementation, but it is redirecting the complete output to one file only:
    `awk '/Pattern\ 1/,/Pattern\ 2/{print > "filename_$var.txt";var=var+1}var' $filename`

Comment: Use `print "filename_"var".txt"`. But you will also have to change the `var=var+1` part, or you will get a new file for each match.

Comment: Yes I do need a new file for each match. But this awk command is giving me the output in one file only

Comment: Even with the modification in the first comment? Note that `print > "filename_$var.txt"` becomes `print > "filename_"var".txt"`

Comment: the modification provided in the first comment redirect every line in a separate file. Not the complete chunk in 2 files as provided in the Output Files section

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the first comment says the modification will do. And a hint on how to solve the rest. You will not always get a full answer, or somebody to code your problem. Sometimes you will just receive a (hopefully helpful) piece of information, to keep trying on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`awk '{if ($0 ~ /Pattern 1/) a++} {print >> "file"a}' file`

First `awk` is looking if the first column is starting with the desired pattern.

If so, the not introduced variable `a` icrements to `a=1`.

Second awk appends everything from *Pattern 1* to *Pattern 2* to the compound string **`file`a** as a file.

I hope this helps.